# How to send variable type integer from Flutter to mysql using php too?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to send integer data from flutter to mysql but it doesn't register in the database. I think the problem is because the variable is of integer type, because if I make it of type string it registers it in the database.

An int parse has not worked for me.

edad is the intreger data.

What would be the best solution.
I would really appreciate the help
code flutter/Dart:::

```
Future PrividerPruebaRegistroCliente(String Contrasena,String correo,String apodo,String apellido, int edad ) async {
    try{
    
      var Url= Uri.parse("http://192.168.0.105/PruebaRati/Prueba Php/Modelo_Php/RatiDemo/ProviderPrueba.php");
      var response = await http.post(Url,

        body:{
          'contrasena' :Contrasena,
          'correo' :correo,
          'apodo' :apodo,
          'apellido' :apellido,
          'edad' :edad
        },
      ).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 90)) ;
   
    }on TimeoutException catch(e){
      print("Tardo mucho la conexion");
    }on Error catch(e){
      print("Error de Http");
    }
  }

------


<?php

require("database connection");

if($conex){

    echo("conexion correcta");
   }else{
  
   
    echo("conexion incorrecta");
   }

   $contrasena = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_POST['contrasena']);
   $correo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_POST['correo']);
   $apodo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_POST['apodo']);
   $apellido = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_POST['apellido']);
   $edad = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_POST['edad']);


        $consulta ="INSERT  into nametable(contrasenia,correo,apodo,apellido,edad)Values ('$contrasena','$correo','$apodo','$apellido','$edad')";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta); 

     if($resultado){  
     
       echo(" correct  query");
      }else{
     
       echo("error  query");
      }
    
    ?>
```

Comment: In the INSERT statement values you have `'$edad'`, this means string value. Remove the quotes, use simply `$edad`. And always use prepared statements when working with user input in PHP, `mysqli_real_escape_string` is not enough to prevent SQL injection.

Comment: It is also worth considering to use `jsonEncode` when submitting post body, like: `body: jsonEncode({'contrasena': ....})`.

Comment: I did it but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. I cast or convert the variable `$edad`, like this:

```
$edad = mysqli_real_escape_string($conex,$_POST['edad']); 
$edadcast = (int)$edad;
```

and after put it in the insert into.